# C# Parent child interfaces

Tags: c#, interface

I have an interface being used within another interface, no problem there. However, the implementation of the parent doesn't except the implementation of the child as having the interface.

```
public interface IGroupInfo
{
    IPictureInfo picture { get; set; }
}
public interface IPictureInfo {}

public class GroupInfo : IGroupInfo
{
    public PictureInfo picture { get; set; }
}

public class PictureInfo : IPictureInfo 
{ }
```

It seems strange this doesn't work since PictureInfo DOES implement IPictureInfo. Is there some workaround to this, am I doing something wrong here ?

I'm trying to put Interfaces onto generated (partial) classes and cannot change (in this example) the 'GroupInfo' class, as it would break my code the next time it's generated. (these are classes generated by WSDL.EXE (Soapcalls))

thanks,
Jurjen

Answer (score 2):

To keep compiler calm you have to specify *exact* return type, so in your case it has to be

```
IPictureInfo ,
```

so your code will look like:

```
public class GroupInfo : IGroupInfo
{
    public IPictureInfo picture { get; set; }
}
```

Compiler *has to know* exact type he hat to deal with during compilation in order to be able to construct syntax tree. Think, that there could be other 1000s of types that implement the same interface.

Answer (score 1):

Think about your property as two methods (because that's what it is):

```
public interface IGroupInfo
{
    IPictureInfo GetPicture();
    void SetPicture( IPictureInfo value );
}
```

So this interface tells us that anyone implementing it will have two methods, one that returns an IPictureInfo and one that accepts an IPictureInfo.  So what happens in your case when you try to implement it this way:

```
public class GroupInfo : IGroupInfo
{
    public PictureInfo GetPicture();
    public void SetPicture( PictureInfo value );
}
```

The problem here is you're not actually implementing the interface correctly, because your `GroupInfo` class will only accept a specific implementation of `IPictureInfo` (specifically `PictureInfo`) instead of being able to accept any implementation of `IPictureInfo` (which the interface says it should be able to).

I'm not aware of any simple way to get around this with a single property.  You could split it up into two separate methods, because then you could specify covariance/contravariance on the types like so:

```
public interface IGroupInfo<out TGet, in TSet> 
    where TGet : IPictureInfo
    where TSet : IPictureInfo
{
    TGet GetPicture();
    void SetPicture( TSet value );
}
```

There's a couple disadvantages with this.  Firstly you don't have one unified concrete interface, which may not be what you want.

I don't know off the top of my head if C# permits covariant implementation of an interface since I almost never have a need for it (I don't think that it does, but I'm not sure).  For example, even if your interface was this:

```
public interface IGroupInfo
{
    IPictureInfo Picture { get; }
}
```

I'm not sure that this would compile:

```
public class GroupInfo : IGroupInfo
{
    public PictureInfo Picture { get; }
}
```

Even though it seems to be a reasonable thing to do.

EDIT: Just checked and that last example won't compile, the return types must match.